# Docker: Container File keep growing

Tags: docker

I am running the latest version of the Wordpress-Image in a docker-container.
After a while the container file /var/lib/docker/containers gets really really large.
After checking the disk usage in the instance I saw that the container itself uses 11G but the Docker Container-File is about 200G.

Why is there a such high difference between the container size and the original size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have try to watch your container logs ?
You can set a max-size in your command line or in your yml.
[Doc is here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)

Exemple:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    nginx:
        ports:
            - '80:80'
        volumes:
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
        restart: always
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 1g
        image: nginx
```

Comment: Thanks for your response you were correct. If you need to tempoary fix the size of the Logfile you can use the following command on linux. ```echo "" > $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)```